# TYPO3 v6.2x GeneralUtility getUniqueName what is alternative?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I see deprecated log of [TYPO3 v6.2x](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/deprecated.html#_deprecated000064) 
There are many functions remove from GeneralUtility.php 
 
Is there any alternative of GeneralUtility::getUniqueName($theFile, $theDest, $dontCheckForUnique=0); ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The function is removed because it's not needed anymore since `FAL` was introduced in `TYPO3 6.0`. You can find alternatives in the `FileReference` object see: [FileReference Class Reference](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_reference.html).

Methods like [getIdentifier()](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_reference.html#a6da3f4f9718ce7343730b457b255b477) and [getPublicUrl()](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_reference.html#acba22af55b6e8e0d7ab7282e932fca0c) can now be used.

Comment: Hi, thank for you answer. But I don't need for upload images or upload any other files. I have BE extension that create files and later will use[filetype: txt,html] same like extension builder, so I need to check in folder if already name taken.